# Finding a matrix $M_{n\times m}$ that minimizes a sum conditional on $M1_m=c_m$ and $1_n^tM=c_n$

Tags: optimization

I am trying to implement a paper, and one of the problems that I need to solve is the following:

The domain is $$\Pi(\pi_0, \pi_1)=\{w\in\mathcal M_{K_0,\,K_1}(\mathbb R^+) : w1_{K_1}=\pi_0 \text{ and }1_{K_0}^tw=\pi_1\}$$

and I want to find $$\min_{w\in\Pi(\pi_0,\pi_1)}\sum_{k,\,l}w_{kl}f(k,l)$$

where $f(k, l)$ is completely determined (plug and chug given $k$ and $l$).

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [transportation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)#Discrete_version_and_linear_programming_formulation) and can be solved via linear programming or a specialized network algorithm.